# Haxe 3 returns empty CallStack

Tags: haxe, callstack

I am following the book "Professional Haxe and Neko" written by Franco Ponticelli and Lee McColl-Sylvester.

Chapter 7-When Things Go Wrong is about errors and exceptions

When I follow the code outlined on pg.192 (which I have minimized here) I have

```haxe
class CallStack {
    public static function main():Void {
        var i:Int = 0;
        i = multiply(i, 6);
    }

    public static function multiply(a,b) {
        return a * traceStack(b);
    }

    public static function traceStack(a) {
        var cs = haxe.CallStack.callStack();
        trace(haxe.CallStack.toString(cs));
        return a;
    }
}
```

When I compile this code it returns an empty callStack.

According to the Haxe API the `callStack()` function

> Returns the call stack elements, or an empty array if not available.

So my questions are these,
Why wouldn't the stack elements be available?
What else would cause the callStack function to return an empty Array?
Is there a better method to use to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

Stack traces are likely not available unless you are running in debug mode.

Comment: True: The haxe.CallStack.callStack() function is only available in debug mode.  I am in debug mode and it is still returning empty.

Comment: What target are you compiling for?

Comment: Flash. It is the only example output outlined in the book to compare.

Comment: I just ran your code and I do get a proper call stack, so it's probably an issue with the way you have your compiler or flash debugging setup.